# Dependant ComboBoxes in C++ QT4

Tags: c++, qt4

I am new to Qt4 as well as C++, I am trying to create a GUI in qt4. How can I add entries in a combo box based on the string selected in another combo box?Say,my comboBox_1 has two entries "2.4GHz" and "5GHz". If the user selects "2.4GHz" then I want my ComboBox_2 to have entries from 1 to 12 and if the user selects "5GHz" then I want the ComboBox_2 to have different entries. How do I do this? please help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First thing came to my mind is to use [QComboBox::currentIndexChanged()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) signal and connect it to a slot, e.g.:

```
connect(&comboBox_1, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
        this, SLOT(populateComboBox2(int)));
```

Then you need to define `populateComboBox2(int)`. The parameter will be passed automatically and will indicate currently selected index in combo box 1. Using this index you can understand what is selected in combo box 1 and populate combo box 2 accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Donotalo for the answer, but can u please elaborate it a little more. How will i retrieve the parameter that is passed on to "populateComboBox2"?As u said,using the index i can populate combobox_2 accordingly but how do I know what index is passed, in order to use it?.I am not very clear.

Comment: in my example the function `populateComboBox2` has a parameter, that's the changed index of combo box 1.

Comment: please try it yourself. typically index >= 0.

Comment: i tried if(index==0)//the code                                        if(index==1)//the code. Did not work for me. Anyways,thanks for your help.:)

Comment: Have you created a function with the slots modifier before it? It seems you either did not create such a function to receive the signal or the connection has failed.

Comment: yes, i did create the function. The problem was in my connect statement, got it now.thanks for all the help.:)